# Google Play game sign in failed

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm making a tutorial to connect to "google play game service" and a pop up still appear mentioning that "failed to sign in. plesae check your network connection and try again"

Everything is setup correctly, SHA1, package name, app_id, and any other related to configuration.

Two strange message appear in the log:

The fist is "You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view."

The second is "disconnect() called when client was already disconnected"

is there any possible solution?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The warning about setViewForPopups() seems to be harmless, I have seen it frequently, and is not related to signin issues.

The disconnect() called when already disconnected is most likely related to moving through the (re)connection logic.  Did you get one of the samples working successfully?

Comment: now I'm following this tutorial [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) but it's not working for me.
Loading sign appears and then disappeared and nothing happens.
I can't get what causes the problem?!

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the logs?, then if it is still not obvious what's going on, post the logs as part of your question. I suggest going over the sample instructions again, checking every step.

Comment: The log shows that the response code is 10002.
I think it's the only thing may have any importance.

Comment: This usually means something is not configured correctly. Check the app id from the play games console matches the one in the xml file.  Also check that you are logging on with the user that created the game or that the email address is added as a tester.